# Do NPCs get an Investigation check vs Thaumaturgy?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, skills, illusion

Thaumaturgy creates effects, such as sounds, that could technically be considered illusions.  As with the Minor Illusion spell, do characters that make Intelligence (Investigation) checks vs the spell-save DC get to correctly characterize the Thaumaturgy effects as illusions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**No**

First, and most importantly, they don't because the text of the spell doesn't mention one.

Second, Thaumaturgy is a *Transmutation* spell - these things are *not* illusions, they actually happen.